# ms access unbound datasheet or alternative control

Tags: forms, ms-access, controls

I want to have an unbound datasheet control in ms access forms or any other alternative tabular data showing control, where I can add rows dynamically and save it to database on form submission not on each next row.
I tried bound datasheet but it saves records as new rows is created, is there some property or method which prevent record saving automatically.
or any other alternative.
below is snap (red portion is not created, I want like this).
actually I want to save order
which has child table order_details
for order details I want this control

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the records have to exist somewhere.

Use a temp table where you create 10 or so empty records before opening the form, and delete all records when you close the form.